# Odoo 13 CRM Kanban hide column to specific groups

Tags: odoo-13

I'm developing a module to customize some CRM featured on Odoo 13 ED, currently the stage is:

- COLUMN 1
- COLUMN 2
- COLUMN 3
- COLUMN 4

I have created 2 user role:

- ROLE 1
- ROLE 2

I want to display only COLUMN1-COLUMN2 if user is ROLE1, and COLUMN3-COLUMN4 if user ROLE2

how can i do that? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved by creating custom record rule on crm.stage

Something like

```
<record id="crm_stage_rule_venditori" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">crm.stage.venditore</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="base.model_crm_stage" />
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('group_venditore'))]" />
    <field name="domain_force" eval="[('id','in',(1,6))]" />
    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>
</record>
```

Domain something like: [('id','in',(1,6))]